# JavaScript get requests with form value

Tags: javascript, node.js

Having issues figure out how to create a GET request to another domain which gets that website html content. The Form Data is part of the get requests which is used.

```
<form name="login">
    <div class="login">

    <input type="text" placeholder="User Name" name="userid"><br>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="pswrd"><br>
    <input type="fromdate" placeholder="From date" name="startdate"><br>
    <input type="Todate" placeholder="To Date" name="todaysdate"><br>
    <input type="button" onclick="check(this.form)" value="Check Data Usage"/>

    </div>

function check(form)
{
    var request = new Request({
    url: '"http://dashboard.somesite.io/DashboardDataServices.asmx/GetMyUsage?userName="+form.userid.value+"&password="+form.userid.value+"&fromDate="+form.startdate.value+"&toDate="+form.todaysdate.value'
method: 'GET'
    });
    fetch(request);
};
```

I get usual problems:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: check is not defined
>       at HTMLInputElement.onclick

Comment: Refer this : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request

Comment: Where is the function `check` placed within HTML or linked using `<script>` element? `Request` expects first parameter to be a string or a `Request` object

Comment: its placed within the body after the the form element.

Comment: Have you tried `new Request(url, {method:"GET"})`?

Answer (score 2):

put your javascript code between `<script>` and `</script>`

```
<script>
function check(form)
{
    var request = new Request({
    url: '"http://dashboard.somesite.io/DashboardDataServices.asmx/GetMyUsage?userName="+form.userid.value+"&password="+form.userid.value+"&fromDate="+form.startdate.value+"&toDate="+form.todaysdate.value'
method: 'GET'
    });
    fetch(request);
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have closed your div but your form is still not closed with `</form>` tag.
You can even call an onSubmit function in  tag like this:

```
<form onsubmit="yourfunction()">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```